# Adding values to a dictionary key in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to scan text and extract data after certain key word.  In this case, I'm scanning a `sql` file.  My dictionary will be structured like this (nested):

```
my_dict = {sql_file:{'select': table_name, 'join': table_name}}
```

I have a loop that goes through the sql file, finds the key word and extracts the table for each file in a directory.  However, because I need to update the dictionary after scanning for the `select` key word *then* come back and update the dictionary for the `join` keyword, the update ends up *overwriting* my original dictionary values.  Here's how the loop works.

```
for key, val in file_dict.items(): # I have a dictionary that has {filename:sql_script} for key,val
    for match in select.finditer(val): # regex iterator to find all matches
        if match.group(1):
            my_dict[sql_file] = {'select': match.group(1)})


for key, val in file_dict.items(): # I have a dictionary that has {filename:sql_script} for key,val
        for match in join.finditer(val): # regex iterator to find all matches
            if match.group(1):
                my_dict[sql_file] = {'join': match.group(1)})
```

This doesn't end up adding the `select` matches, then adding the `join` matches, it just overwrites the `select` and replaces it with the `join`.  Dictionaries don't have an append method, so I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: `my_dict[sql_file]['select'] = match.group(1)`

Comment: You don't need an append method, just assign the key you want.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your `my_dict[sql_file]` you get another dictionary containing `{'select': table_name, 'join': table_name}`. Therefore you can access this dictionary just like you did with the other one:

```py
for key, val in file_dict.items():
    for match in select.finditer(val):
        if match.group(1):
            my_dict[sql_file]['select'] = match.group(1)


for key, val in file_dict.items():
        for match in join.finditer(val):
            if match.group(1):
                my_dict[sql_file]['joinn'] = 'join': match.group(1)
```